# Is it possible to run the Network Link Conditioner with Instruments using Automated UI Testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

The title pretty much says it all.

Is it possible to run the Network Link Conditioner with Instruments using Automated UI Testing?

i.e. can you change the status of the network from the Automation tool of Instruments and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This might feel like a long way round, but now with multi-app testing in Xcode 9 you could use XCTest UI automation to switch to settings.app and change the network conditioning in the developer pane. There's more detailed information in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738200/5499522) I wrote.